# climate of a planet of only archipelagoes and shallow seas

Tags: planets, climate

In a scifi universe I'm currently writing up, a colony was established on a weird world. strangely, it's a habitable planet with an extremely shallow sea, with an average depth of 4 meters, excluding the occasional 2 km deep rift valley. The planet is also dotted with chains of islands, mostly small piles of sand, the largest island is about the size of Earth's Madagascar Island. Volcanism is rare despite the evidence of a magnetosphere and tectonic activity.

But what would the climate of a world that is nearly all shallow ocean be like? How would the currents work? would it be a sunny tropical paradise or a stormy hell hole? And would it be a good place to put up a beach resort for human colonists?

Specific characteristics of said planet

- 90% the size of the earth
- Gravity of .95 gs
- the surface is nearly 99% ocean
- ~1 Au from its parent star
- said parent star is a little dimmer than our own Sol
- deep open oceans are rare on this planet, with most parts going no deeper than 20 meters
- habitable, complex multicellular life is present, and an atmosphere like Earth's is also present

Comment: I'm sure I'd heard this question before, but I can't find any duplicates. Possibly related, though: [Can an Earth-like world of shallow, global, seas be stable over geological time?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/211348/can-an-earth-like-world-of-shallow-global-seas-be-stable-over-geological-time), [Archipelago worlds build up atmospheric oxygen faster?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/150253/archipelago-worlds-build-up-atmospheric-oxygen-faster)

Comment: Putting a little bit more thought into this... where does your sand come from? You don't really have an equivalent of Earth's sand-forming environments.

Comment: @StarfishPrime a mix of rock broken apart by tides, coral/snail analogs being broken apart, reefs, and a "Mud" mix made from decaying organic compounds and fine silt, that's how the sand is formed. I didn't put it in the initial question because I thought it wasn't that important of information.

Comment: So not sand, then. Silt might work, but you do end up with mudworld…

Comment: @StarfishPrime It's a mix of both, silt in the more barren areas with sand around reefs and islands. I going to just assume that the sand piles that extend above the sea level is just the remains of some big rocks that were broken up by waves and wind. How they got their? Maybe being flung out by a volcano?

Comment: Fair warning: climate is *incredibly complex* and asking on behalf of an entire planet is a pretty tall order that often violates the Help Center's book rule (see [help/dont-ask]). That means you're likely to receive very generalized answers. Can you explain why you're asking the question? What kinds of effects are you looking for or what type of information do you want? At a guess, your world will have a lot of clouds.

Comment: I always wonder if such things are even possible from a cosmological standpoint. We know so little about it, but there are interesting things in geology that hint that we'd only have tectonics with larger oceans, and if we have no tectonics, then also what water we do have might soon go away. And what of the water cycle? How can there be one in such a place? No glaciers, not much in the way of rivers, nothing to feed the shallow oceans. Of course, this could be my complete misunderstanding of those concepts.

Comment: @JohnO from my understanding, as long as you have water evaporating into the atmosphere, condensating, and falling out of the sky, you got a basic water cycle

Comment: similar concept?   https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/201259/possible-reef-world

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The climate on your world would, to a good approximation, be similar to that on Earth. The oceanic currents would be different, but in broad terms its an Earth analog, Earth is after all 70% ocean. o

Obviously the effects of land masses / mountains would be missing so just extrapolate Earth's oceanic climate around the entire planet. Might as well take the Pacific Ocean as a starting point as it more or less covers half the planet anyway.

Comment: Kinda my thoughts too. Presumably take "Pacific Island-chain weather" and assume that's everywhere. Problem is I'm not sure if making the oceans 20m deep would change that. Are hurricanes worse because the planet is mostly ocean, or non-existent because the oceans are mostly 20m deep?

Comment: I think the 20m deep oceans are probably deep enough to mimic our oceans for hurricane purposes. I doubt that water below 20m has any major effect on a passing hurricane on Earth as convection from such a depth takes time. The main players are surface temperature and atmospheric effects. That said its hard to be certain. timehttps://www.weather.gov/source/zhu/ZHU_Training_Page/tropical_stuff/hurricane_anatomy/hurricane_anatomy.html

Answer (score 3):

I think planets with (carbon-based) life but shallow oceans make for an interesting combination. Organic matter and nutrients from dead matter in our world descend deep into the ocean through the process of [marine snow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marine_snow). To the best of my knowledge this explains why on our planet the CO$_2$ concentration has been able to get so low (100's of ppms in stead of 10's of percents): the carbon was fixed from the atmosphere by photosynthesizing cyanobacteria and then fell to the ocean floor by virtue of the overdensity of the dead organic matter. On your planet, there will be an abundant ecosystem on the ocean floor efficiently recycling (burning) whatever is deposited there and so the atmospherical $CO_2$ will likely stay very high. So the greenhouse effect is going to be very strong here (but if the star is sufficiently dim there may not be a problem) and the atmosphere not exactly breathable for humans.

Of course you might circumvent that predicament by having a weird primordial chemical composition for your planet (very scarce C), but you're probably finetuning then.